# Unable to change specific text color in EditText

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

Problem: The user types in a message, and when a specific word is typed in, the color of only that word changes. This change is to be real-time. When I run the code below, the app continues to run and behaves as if it wasn't there.

```
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final EditText messageBodyView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message_body);
    String mMessageBody = messageBodyView.getText().toString();      

    messageBodyView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

       @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (hasFocus) {
                Spannable spannable;

                for (String word: mSelectedWords) {
                    int index = mMessageBody.indexOf(word);
                    spannable = new SpannableString
                            (mMessageBody.substring(index, index));
                    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,0,0);
                   messageBodyView.setText(spannable);
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

What's going on here?

**BUMP** I am still not able to find a solution to this problem, I will be grateful for any helpful pointers.

Comment: **BUMP** I am still not able to find a solution to this problem, I will be grateful for any helpful pointers.

Comment: there are so many things wrong with this code so it is hard to point on something specific
1. mMessageBody.substring(index, index) = will be empty string
2. setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,0,0); will span nothing
3. what do you expect with OnFocusChangeListener ..

Comment: Is it not the purpose of this website to help programmers, beginners or otherwise, learn from their mistakes? It is extremely disheartening to know my post is being ignored because "there are so many things wrong" with it, when that should be the sole reason to not ignore it.

Comment: and first lesson from my comment that you should learn is before posting what comes to your mind check it first. second lesson is fix what I told

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
edit_txt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String[] input = edit_txt1.getText().toString().split(" ");
            String output = "";
            for(int i=0; i<input.length;i++){
                if(input[i].equals("Word")) input[i]="<font color=red>"+input[i]+ "</font>";
            }
            for(int i=0; i<input.length;i++) output = output +input[i];
            edit_txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(output));
        }
    });
```